# How do I create and populate a List<string[]> in line? (C#)

Tags: c#

I need to create and populate in line (is there a word for this operation?) an instance of `List<string[]>`. How do I do that?

Comment: The terms you are looking for us Object and Collection Initializers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var list = new List<string[]> 
{ 
    new[] { "One", "Two", "Three" },
    new[] { "Four", "Five", "Six" }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var test = new List<string> { "test", "test2" };
```

Comment: That would work if the OP was using `List<String>`, but its actually `List<String[]>`

Answer (score 2):

do you mean this?

```
var stringList = new List<string[]> 
{ 
    new string[] { "stringa1", "stringa2", "stringa3" }, 
    new string[] { "stringb1", "stringb2", "stringb3" },
    new string[] { "stringc1", "stringc2", "stringc3" }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list_array = new List<string[]> {
   new[]{"a", "b", "c" }, new[] {"f", "g", "h"}};
```

Comment: Does `new[]` take its type from the list, like `var`?

Comment: Yeah, the type is inferred by the values in the array.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx)